# How to brand SharePoint addins

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm building some SharePoint add-ins.

Some are SFPx web parts, others are SharePoint hosted add-ins.

How to customize icons and pictures for these applications ?

I'm looking for :

- change the icon in the "add an application"
- change the image, description in the application details page
- change the icon once the application is added in the site content page
- change the picture and description in the permission review modal

For the later, I've been able to add an image with `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/relationships/manifest-icon` as open xml content type.

PS: I don't use VS (full) for packaging the add-ins, because my add-ins are written using .Net 6.

PS2: The add-ins are not published through the office marketplace, but are added to the site collection app catalog.

I looked through the docs, but nothing explain how to do it (or at least I didn't found)

Answer (score 0):

For SPFx web parts, you can preconfigure the SPFx web part using manifest JSON file inside `./src/webparts` folders.

For example:

```
./src/webparts/gallery/GalleryWebPart.manifest.json
```

Inside manifest file, you have to change the `preconfiguredEntries` property. You can set the web part title, description, icon for the web part that is displayed in the toolbox using `officeFabricIconFontName` or you use use `iconImageUrl`, etc.

Check Microsoft official documentation for more information: [Simplify adding web parts with preconfigured entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/simplify-adding-web-parts-with-preconfigured-entries)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, it applies to the webpart gallery, not the application catalog.